# Android Bluetooth Discovery API Isn't Working on Android 6.0

Tags: java, android, bluetooth, bluetooth-device-discovery

I've made an app, that is discovering nearby bluetooth devices and etc. I can get bluetooth adapter, open-close processes, get paired devices, discovering process. Everthing is fine but discovery process isn't working properly.

I tested my app on 5 different real devices. At the moment I realized I have a problem on Android version but I'm not sure about that.

**My app's discovery process is working on,**

- Huawei P7         - Android Version: 4.4.2
- Sony Xperia Z     - Android Version: 5.1.1
- Samsung Galaxy J3 - Android Version: 5.1.1

**My app's discovery process isn't working on,**

- Samsung Galaxy S7 - Android Version: 6.0.1
- Samsung Galaxy J7 - Android Version: 6.0.1

**MainActivity.java**

```
package com.sphinxlike.bluetoothexample;

import android.bluetooth.BluetoothAdapter;
import android.bluetooth.BluetoothDevice;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.IntentFilter;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Parcelable;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Set;

import static java.lang.System.out;


public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    /* DECLERATIONS */
    // Button
    Button openBtn = null;                                      // Open button
    Button closeBtn = null;                                     // Close button
    Button listBtn = null;                                      // Paired devices list button
    Button searchBtn = null;                                    // Discovery new devices button

    // Bluetooth
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = null;          // Local bluetooth adapter variable
    private static final int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;             // Bluetooth open intent variable
    String mDeviceName = null;
    String mDeviceAddress = null;
    public static String EXTRA_ADDRESS = "device_address";

    // XML
    TextView tvDeviceName = null;                               // To show local bluetooth device's name
    TextView tvBluetoothState = null;                           // To show bluetooth state
    ListView lvDeviceList = null;                               // To list paired devices or discovered devices

    // Set, List, Array Adapter
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> mPairedDevicesSet = null;      // Paired devices Set
    private Set<BluetoothDevice> mNewDevicesSet = null;         // New devices Set
    ArrayAdapter mPairedDevicesAdapter = null;                  // Paired devices array adapter
    ArrayAdapter mNewDevicesAdapter = null;                     // New devices array adapter
    ArrayList bluetoothDeviceList = null;                       // Listing bluetooth devices
    private ArrayList<BluetoothDevice> btDeviceList = new ArrayList<BluetoothDevice>();

    // Bluetooth State Updater
    private Handler mHandler;                                   // Loop in UI

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        // Initializes UI elements
        tvDeviceName = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.deviceName);
        tvBluetoothState = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bluetoothState);
        openBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.openBluetooth);
        closeBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.closeBluetooth);
        listBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.listBluetooth);
        searchBtn = (Button)findViewById(R.id.searchBluetooth);
        lvDeviceList = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.deviceList);

        // Bluetooth adapter
        mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();

        // Button checks
        openBtn.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        closeBtn.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        listBtn.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        searchBtn.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

        // To update bluetooth state text view
        tvBluetoothState.setText(String.valueOf(mBluetoothAdapter.getState()));


        // If the phone does not support bluetooth adapter
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            tvBluetoothState.setText("Your phone has not Bluetooth Adapter");
            openBtn.setEnabled(false);
            closeBtn.setEnabled(false);
            listBtn.setEnabled(false);
            searchBtn.setEnabled(false);
        }

        // Updater loop
        mHandler = new Handler();
        mHandler.post(mUpdate);
    }

    // Updater Loop
    private Runnable mUpdate = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getBluetoothState();
            mHandler.postDelayed(this, 500);
        }
    };

    // Button onClick method
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.openBluetooth:
                if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    Intent bluetoothAcIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
                    startActivityForResult(bluetoothAcIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is already open", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.closeBluetooth:
                if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                    mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
                } else {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Bluetooth is already close", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            case R.id.listBluetooth:
                pairedDevicesList();
                break;
            case R.id.searchBluetooth:
                IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();

                filter.addAction(BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND);
                filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_STARTED);
                filter.addAction(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_DISCOVERY_FINISHED);

                registerReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver, filter);
                mBluetoothAdapter.startDiscovery();

                break;
        }
    };

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        unregisterReceiver(mBroadcastReceiver);

        super.onDestroy();
    }

    private final BroadcastReceiver mBroadcastReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            String action = intent.getAction();
            // Whenever a remote Bluetooth device is found
            if (BluetoothDevice.ACTION_FOUND.equals(action)) {
                // Get the BluetoothDevice object from the Intent
                BluetoothDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(BluetoothDevice.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), device.getName() + ":" + device.getAddress(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
//                lvDeviceList.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesAdapter);     // Set list view elements with adapter elements
            }
        }
    };

    // Show bluetooth state on UI
    public void getBluetoothState() {
        tvDeviceName.setText("Device Name: " + mBluetoothAdapter.getName());
        switch(mBluetoothAdapter.getState()) {                                // Set bluetooth state text view
            case 10:    // STATE_OFF
                tvBluetoothState.setText("Bluetooth is closed");
                bluetoothDeviceList = new ArrayList();              // Initialize global array list variable that is declared
                mPairedDevicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bluetoothDeviceList);     // Get array list and use in array adapter
                lvDeviceList.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesAdapter);     // Set list view elements with adapter elements
                break;
            case 11:    // STATE_TURNING_ON
                tvBluetoothState.setText("Bluetooth is opening");
                break;
            case 12:    // STATE_ON
                tvBluetoothState.setText("Bluetooth is opened");
                break;
            case 13:    // STATE_TURNING_OFF
                tvBluetoothState.setText("Bluetooth is closing");
                break;
        }

        // If bluetooth adapter  -> Set buttons
        if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            // Enable listing button
            listBtn.setEnabled(true);
            searchBtn.setEnabled(true);
        } else {
            // Disable listing button
            listBtn.setEnabled(false);
            searchBtn.setEnabled(false);
        }
    }

    // Get paired device list and adapt to list view
    public void pairedDevicesList()
    {
        if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Open the Bluetooth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            mPairedDevicesSet = mBluetoothAdapter.getBondedDevices();       // Get paired devices
            bluetoothDeviceList = new ArrayList();                      // Initialize global array list variable that is declared

            if (mPairedDevicesSet.size()>0) {
                for (BluetoothDevice bt : mPairedDevicesSet) {              // for-each loop
                    mDeviceName = bt.getName();
                    mDeviceAddress = bt.getAddress();
                    bluetoothDeviceList.add(mDeviceName + "\n" + mDeviceAddress);              // get the device name and add to array list object
                }
            } else if (mPairedDevicesSet.size()<=0){
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No paired devices", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
            mPairedDevicesAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, bluetoothDeviceList);     // Get array list and use in array adapter
            lvDeviceList.setAdapter(mPairedDevicesAdapter);     // Set list view elements with adapter elements
        }
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.sphinxlike.bluetoothexample.MainActivity"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:hint="Device Name"
        android:id="@+id/deviceName"/>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp">

        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/openBluetooth"
            android:text="B. Open"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/closeBluetooth"
            android:text="B. Close"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/listBluetooth"
            android:text="List Paired"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"/>
        <Button
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/searchBluetooth"
            android:text="Search"
            android:textAllCaps="false"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:hint="Bluetooth State"
        android:id="@+id/bluetoothState"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:gravity="center"/>

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/deviceList">

    </ListView>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firstly, thanks @Tomasz Czura. I solved problem with multiple runtime permission request.
[Android Developer 6.0 Changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/marshmallow/android-6.0-changes.html) page says:

> To access the hardware identifiers of nearby external devices via Bluetooth and Wi-Fi scans, your app must now have the ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION or ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION permissions:

So, I added permission to AndroidManifest.XML:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
```

then I rearranged my activity like this:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
...
    int ACTION_REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION = 1;  // Any number

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        ...

        int pCheck = this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION");
        pCheck += this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION");
        pCheck += this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN");
        pCheck += this.checkSelfPermission("Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH");
        if (pCheck != 0) {
            this.requestPermissions(new String[]{Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION,
            Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN, Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH}, ACTION_REQUEST_MULTIPLE_PERMISSION);
        }
    }
}
```

It worked.

Answer (score 0):

You have to ask for Bluetooth permissions at run time in Android 6.0 -

```
ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(..)
```

Comment: But I can open-close bluetooth, get bluetooth adapter and get paired devices. And they don't need runtime permission ? Is discovery api need runtime permission?

Comment: Try to request also location permission `android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION`

Comment: Do you get any errors? What do you have in your logs?

Comment: I used code on bottom at OnCreate() method,
`try {`
`ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this, new String[]` `{Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH,`
`Manifest.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN}, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);`
`} catch {RuntimeException e) {`
`Log.e("Error on runtime request: ", e.getMessage());`
`}`

But can't get error message?